# Saber las veces que se cumple una condición dentro de una lista en python

Tags: python

estoy aprendiendo pyhton y tengo la inquietud de como contar las veces que se cumple una condición sobre los índices de una lista.

Ejemplo:
Tengo un X = 3
Y quiero.saber cuántas veces se cumple x>3 dentro de la lista Numero. En ese caso 2 veces ( el 4 y 5).
Numero = [1,2,1,4,5]

Intente con for x in range (Numero) ,puse un if y un contador pero me sale error.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código y el mensaje de error por favor?

Comment: podrías poner el código que has echo, además del error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando comprensión de listas con condición.

```
[x for x in numero if x > 3]
```

Es una comprensión común y corriente, pero el `if x > 3` la transforma en condicional: el elemento se incorpora a la nueva lista sólo si la condición se cumple.

Teniendo la lista de valores mayores que 3, sólo quede contarlos usando `len`.

**Solución**

```
numero = [1,2,1,4,5]
print(len([x for x in numero if x > 3]))
```

Comment: ¿dónde queda en el foro no se hacen tareas?

Comment: Es un sitio, no un foro @tincopasan

Comment: @DanteS. bueno, ¿eso cambia el sentido de la pregunta?¿dónde queda en el "sitio" no se hacen tareas?

Comment: @tincopasan el OP afirma haberlo intentado por si mismo con un método especifico. Yo quería pruebas de que realmente aplicó ese método, por eso le pedí el código. Supongo que para Candid Moe la pregunta tenía suficiente evidencia de que hubo esfuerzo del otro lado y decidió responder. Pero son solo suposiciones...

Comment: @tincopasan. Yo vi a un OP atorado en un problema simple que había intentando resolver, pero que lo había superado. No estaba pidiendo un sistema de facturación ni pasando el enunciado de una tarea. Es una pregunta razonablemente bien formulada. Respondí con una solución apropiada a su nivel que espero le ilumine sobre Python y que sea útil a otros. Creo haber dado +1 al karma del planeta.

Comment: No es una tarea, siento no ser tan específico poniendo el código. Saludos

Comment: @DanteS. ¿entones puedo contestar preguntas sin código en base a mis suposiciones?

Comment: @Candid Moe ¿puedo contestar preguntas en base a que lo considere simple?

Comment: @tincopasan IMHO lo que hizo Candid Moe no perjudicará al OP, ya que de cierto modo demostró que algo intento diciendo masomenos que hizo. Asi que en conclusión, si, puedes contestar en base a suposiciones.

Comment: @MANUELJESUSTUTACHACUASIALPU No hay nada de que disculparse c: Pasa que algunos OPs esperan que les hagamos la tarea. Algo muy común es que peguen su tarea en una pregunta. Y aquí sabemos que responder preguntas cuyos OPs esperan a que les resolvamos las tareas van a hacerles un mal en su proceso de aprendisaje, y eso nos importa. De ahi que nos preocupe tanto que hayas intentado algo antes de preguntar.